# Printer sometimes doesn't print

Tags: 12.04, usb, printing

I installed 12.04LTS and have a DeskJet 1125C connected through USB.
The problem: Sometimes it does not print - in print jobs is status Pending/Processing but print does not start. I discovered if I print some documents then next document simply doesn't print with status processing or status pending. The only way is to disconnect printer from USB and immediately reconnect then works OK some times.

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps anyone, I have these same symptoms (print jobs go to pending and never print) unless my printer is turned on **after** Ubuntu starts up. Therefore, if I have print jobs pending, turning the printer off and then on again is enough to get them going.

Comment: This worked for me! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Running `sudo service cups restart` will restart the printing software, fixing the problem.

I'm a complete Linux novice, but I somehow I hit upon executing the command and it worked without a hitch (I was given a clue when I ran `pgrep hp` and it gave me 2 `hp` processes and one `hp-cups` process).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem but nothing worked. What I did to solve it was go to printers from the dash, right-click my printer and then realised there was no tick next to "enabled". Once I clicked this, it worked again. Something I'd installed must have disabled it for some reason :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems i have fixed it with repalce /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftops file with one from there: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/375763

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are possibly right, but I've discovered it might be an issue with *what* you're printing in combination with the *settings* that you're using.

For example, I tried to print [this simple PDF](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=check-108.pdf), which is just a black and white checkerboard, on my Deskjet 932C. I selected "photo paper" in my print options (because I was using photo paper) and not only did the job get stuck in my queue, but my printer also started to make grinding noises and then began flashing its lights.

So I power-cycled the printer. Printed a test page using normal paper, just to make sure my printer wasn't fried, and ran:

```
lprm
sudo service cups restart
```

and tried printing the checkerboard again with photo paper, and the same thing happened. Then I tried selecting "normal paper" from the options...and it printed perfectly.

I guess the "Print" options shown my some applications doesn't always mess with the actual printer being used.